# How to let a pen pal know it is ok to speak in English

Tags: invitation

I have a new Japanese pen pal and we have only written in Japanese. I would like to clarify (in Japanese) that it is ok if she wants to write in English so she can practice. What would be the most natural way of extending this invitation？ Perhaps:

> 英語は話しましょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

は is a topic marker, so 英語は話す means "English talks". You have to use [で](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/particle-de-expressing-supplementary-information/) and say 英語**で**話す ("to talk **in** English").

> - 英語で話しましょうか。
> - 英語で話しましょう。
> - 英語で話しても大丈夫ですよ。